# Homology of contractible space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I understand that if $f,g: X \to Y$ are maps and $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then the induced maps on the homology groups $f_*$ and $g_*$ are equal. Why does this imply that if $X$ is contractible then $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(X) = 0$ for $n > 0$?

Comment: What map does the identity map induce on homology? What map does the zero map induce on homology? More to the point, this property shows that homology groups are invariant under homotopy equivalence, and contractible spaces are (more or less by definition) homotopy equivalent to a point.

Answer (score 11):

If $X$ is a contractible space, you can take $f=Id_X:X\rightarrow X$ and $g(x)=y$ where $y$ is a fixed point of $X$ so $g$ is a constant map. The maps $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. If $n>0$, $f_*^n: H^n(X)\rightarrow H^n(X)$ is the identity, and $g_*^n=0$.